# How to loop an Api for a variable

Tags: php, api, foreach

```
$a = array("a", "b", "c", "d");
@$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
$arr =  explode(".", $q);

$output = array();
foreach ($a as &$value) {
    if (substr($value, 0, strlen(@$arr[1])) === @$arr[1])
        $output[]= $arr[0] . "." . $value;
}
echo implode('<br>',$output);
```

I want to loop an Api for the variable **$output** the Api is made of PHP code with the title **api.php** does somebody have a good solution for this problem.

**The thing I want**

The output exist most of the time of more than 1 variables so I want to check them al if there are more than 1. So like this:

> nono.a(In red because not available), nono.b(In green because available)

And with the Api you can see the availabilty of the domain.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "I want to loop an Api"? What API? I don't even see a single API request, let alone an attempt to make multiple requests based on a loop.

Comment: @PatrickQ I am new to this so sorry if I am not that good in asking a question about this. What I want is a check via an api if the $output is available (as of a domain name). Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Probably, but _you_ have to tell _us_ what the API is.  You should also do some basic research on using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).  It is still unclear what part of this you're having trouble with.  Do you not know how to make an external request? (see previous link in that case)  Do you not know how to loop over an array?  I'm afraid without some more detail we're not going to be able to provide much help.